# How to accept user input in bash file that is executed using Plink?

Tags: bash, shell, ssh, cmd, plink

I have a simple bash script:

```
echo "Hello!"

read varname

echo "you entered " $varname
```

So it outputs "Hello!" and then accepts user input and outputs text that was entered.

The script can be successfully executed using PuTTY.

Also I can run the script using Plink via Windows `cmd`. I connect to host:

> plink.exe -batch -i C:\path\to\key.ppk user@host

And then I change directory and run the script:

```
cd mydir

bash myscript.sh
```

The script works as required: prints "Hello!" and then ask for input and prints the input.

However if I run the script with the same string with Plink connection:

```
plink.exe -batch -i C:\path\to\key.ppk user@host bash ./mydir/myscript.sh
```

I get the following misfunction: I see "Hello!" output and the cursor is blinking on the next line. But I can't type any character there. The console simply does not react on any key and even on Enter. The only one way to continue is to press Ctrl+C to close the connection.

So how to solve this and make the script to accept input using cmd + Plink if a script is executed using a single line?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you specify a command on Plink command-line, it executes the command in non-interactive session (without a terminal emulation).

Use [`-t` switch](https://the.earth.li/~sgtatham/putty/latest/htmldoc/Chapter3.html#using-cmdline-pty) to force a use of an interactive session (terminal emulation):

```
plink.exe -batch -t -i C:\path\to\key.ppk user@host bash ./mydir/myscript.sh
```